# Rotation of a bar problem

Tags: geometry, vectors, linear-transformations, rotations

I'm having difficulty figuring this out...

Imagine a rod in 3-space.  One end of the rod is fixed at the origin (Point A).  The end that is free is (Point B).  Point B is initially at <0,0,z> pointed in the positive z direction.  The rod may only rotate about the x-axis by (theta) and y-axis by (phi).  It cannot twist (no rotation about the z axis).

1. Point B has been displaced by some angle phi and some angle theta.  Find these two angles.
2. Attach a new rod to the end of Rod-1.  This is Rod-2 whose origin is at (Point B) and end is at (Point C).  The same constraints follow as for Rod-1. Rod-2 is displaced.  Find the angles phi' and theta' against the rotated axis x',y',z' where z' points in the direction of Rod-1.

To solve this problem I did this,

1)
Project Rod-1 into the y-z plane and find the angle between the projection and y to find phi.
Project Rod-1 into the x-z plane and find the angle between the projection and x to find theta.

2)
Rotate the x-axis by (90 - theta) along the y-axis to get x'.
Rotate the z-axis by the angle between Rod-1 and the z-axis along the negative x' axis to get z'.
Take the cross product of z' and x' to get y'

To check that this works,
a) I take the dot product of Rod-1 with z' ->  I should get 1.
b) The dot product of Rod-1 and y' should be 0 and so should the dot product of Rod-1 and x'

This is not the case though.  They are off.  Is this the correct method for rotating this coordinate axis to the orientation of Rod-1?  I need the axis to be rotated so that I can get the angles of Rod-2 against Rod-1.

Comment: In your first case, when you rotate it around x-axis by $\theta$, the y-axis projection is  $z \sin\theta$ and z-axis projection is $z \cos\theta$. It is still in $YZ$ plane. Now if you rotate it around y-axis by $\phi$, the projection on y-axis remains the same. The projection on $XZ$ plane is $z \cos\theta$. The projection on x-axis becomes  $z \cos\theta \sin \phi$.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks!  So the way I found the projections was with vector algebra, By taking Rod-1's vector and subtracting the vector parallel to the x-axis or y-axis, I should get the projection into the y-z  or x-z planes respectively yes?  As for the second part, it's actually very easy and I didn't realize it until I pulled it up into Blender.  Just take the cross product of the Rod-1 with the Z and then rotate the angle difference between the two.  Rotate the other coord vectors the same.  And then you have successfully rotated the coord axis.

Comment: Yes that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to find $\theta$ and $\phi$:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\arccos{\left(\frac{\vec{B}’\cdot\vec{B}}{||B||^{2}}\right)}\\
\\
\theta&=\alpha\frac{\vec{B}\times\vec{B}’}{\left|\left|\vec{B}\times\vec{B}’\right|\right|}\cdot\hat{i}\\
\phi&=\alpha \frac{\vec{B}\times\vec{B}’}{\left|\left|\vec{B}\times\vec{B}’\right|\right|}\cdot\hat{j}
\end{align}
$$

Now define the rotational matrix

$$
\begin{align}
G&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{\left(\theta\right)} & -\sin{\left(\theta\right)} \\
0 & \sin{\left(\theta\right)} & \cos{\left(\theta\right)}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\left(\phi\right)} & 0 & \sin{\left(\phi\right)} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin{\left(\phi\right)} & 0 & \cos{\left(\phi\right)}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

The rotated axis are:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x}’ & \hat{y}’ & \hat{z}’
\end{bmatrix}
&=\left[G\right]
\end{align}
$$